# Why is my Views display limited to 17 lines

Tags: drupal-views

One of my Views displays only 17 lines when I open it. 
I have to refresh the display to get all the lines.

How can I fix that ?

Screen 1 : parameterization :
[image]

Screen 2 : display
[image]

Screen 3 : after refresh
[image]

Comment: I think you need to give more information about this view otherwise it's probably going to get flagged as off-topic since it doesn't even seem to be about CiviCRM. If you can't post a screenshot can you describe it?

Comment: I'm with Demerit, more information is needed to help you through your issue
what is displayed in the view? a mix of drupal and civi data? 
more info, details and screenshots

Comment: I have just edited my question

Comment: It looks like you are on the admin page where you define it so it's just showing a preview. Normally in this section you also define a front end page url or block where it displays for users or staff. If you view it there does it show all?

Comment: No, if I just click on display, the complete list is displayed (25 by 25) ; and the same happens if I am in the user Page : when I open it, only 17 are found, and when I click on display, 131 are found (and displayed 25 by 25).

Comment: I hope that isn't real data in your screenshots! If so I'd suggest changing it for a screenshot with the personal details obscured.